# Is there a way to tell if an object has implemented ToString explicitly in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, properties

I am trying to log information about the state of some objects and classes in my code. Not all the classes or libraries were implemented with Serialization. So I am using Reflection on the Properties to write out an XML document of the state. However, I have a challenge in that some objects like builtin Classes (ie Strings, DateTime, Numbers etc...) have a ToString function that prints out the value of the class in a meaningful way. But for other classes, calling ToString just uses the inherited base ToString to spit out the name of the object type (For example a Dictionary). In that case I want to recursively examine to properties inside that class.

So if anyone can help me with reflection to either figure out if there is a ToString implemented on the property I'm looking at that isn't the base method OR to point out the proper way of using GetValue to retrieve collection properties I would appreciate it.

J

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To determine whether a method has overridden the default `.ToString()` check `MethodInfo.DeclaringType` like so:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("ToString").DeclaringType != typeof(object));
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyOtherClass).GetMethod("ToString").DeclaringType != typeof(object));
}

class MyClass 
{
    public override string ToString() { return ""; }
}

class MyOtherClass {
}
```

Prints out:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Using BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly lets you test it directly.

Comment: But there might be an override inherited from a base class other than object.

Comment: Right. And Hans Passant's suggestion to look only for overrides declared by the object's run-time type therefore falls short.

Comment: well I should have typed @hans or the like, so it's my fault you did.

Comment: Most of the Built In Objects have multiple ToString methods. So I had to modify the example to use the follwoing GetMethod parameters: GetMethod("ToString", System.Type.EmptyTypes)

Comment: It might be good to compare to typeof(ValueType) as well, when it's desirable to detect ToString overrides on structs.