# Constraints on parameters

Tags: c#, constraints, parameters

I have a method that logs out data, and takes bunch of inputs using the params keyword

```
public static void LogData<T>(params object[] parameter)
{
    // log out the data
}
```

I'd like to restrict the inputs to strings and numeric types, and my first thought was to use a where clause.  The obvious issue with this are that you can't use concrete types in a where clause, but you can get around this by noticing that both string and numeric types are IComparable and IConvertible.  I thought this might help:

```
public static void LogData<T>(params T[] parameter)
    where T : IComparable, IConvertible
{
    // log out the data
}
```

This doesn't work because then all the inputs have to be one type.

Is there a way to restrict the inputs to string and numeric types using the params keyword or some other syntax?

Comment: Why would you do that? The only reason why these constraints are available is to give the programmer the possibility to call method, create objects, ect...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do that, when every object has a `ToString` method.

Anyway, you can declare a new class - NumberOrString that will support implicit conversions from a string and the numeric types you want to support. Then have your LogData method accept a `params NumberOrString[] p`

Answer (score 0):

Consiidering you are talking about `strings` **and** `numeric` types, it's not possible. If condition would be **or**, you can define an `optional parameter` of type `List<T>` where `T` is any chosen numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create multiple methods which are essentially overloads using the types I want to support.
might be too much code and repetitive but the basic "log out the data" routine would essentially be reused across all overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one potential solution:

```
public static void LogData(params IConvertible[] parameter)
{
    // log out the data
}
```

Although I wonder if there's actually any reason you need the objects to be IComparable or IConvertible, or if you'd just like to restrict them to known types (i.e. strings or numbers).  I think zmbq's answer might be the way to go.  Or you might even really just want to see if the object implements a useful `ToString` method.  [Here's a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507609/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-an-object-has-implemented-tostring-explicitly-in-c-sha) to find that out (not a compile-time restriction, as you might expect, but at runtime using reflection).